# Sending skype messages from php

Tags: php, skype

I was wondering if it's possible to send skype messages from php without having skype installed. So that you login with php and send messages without any applications. Is this possible.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? To me this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054877/is-it-possible-to-send-skype-chat-messages-from-a-linux-server-without-x) are a good answer.

tl;dr: This is not easily possible from within PHP or node.js

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am unaware of an API that exists with Skype for PHP.

```
<a href="skype:echo123?chat">Chat with Skype demo user</a>
```

I believe that, currently - or as it stands, this is the only method to achieve something as such. This integrates the Skype Protocol for use.

However, you may want to take a look at this: [Skype with PHP](https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/how-to-send-skype-im-programmatically/).

But how accurate that is, I am not sure